# security group not allowing connection to postgres ec2 aws

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, postgresql

Hey im having some trouble allow remote connections to postgres from other ec2 instances using the named security group feature to rules.

I have set the listens directive in postgres.conf to "*" and have allowed all ips in the pg_hba.conf file to

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

i have a security group for the instance trying to connnect called appserver and one called db for the postgres instance.  the db security group allows TCP connections from 5432 from any instance with the appserver security group

However this simply dosent work.  I cannot establish a connection to postgres remotely.  To validate things are working with postgres in general i allowed 0.0.0.0/0 for the db security group for port 5432 and it worked.

I really dont know what else to try now!

Comment: Are you sure that the instance from which you are trying to make connection, is a part of appserver security group .. because usually it works ?

Comment: @GeekRide yeh 100%

Comment: Is this setup in VPC or just simply EC2 and no VPC is included ?

Comment: @GeekRide this is simply EC2 and no vpc

Comment: are you using an external dns to connect from one instance to another? i.e db.test.com and not xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazon.com?

Comment: @AlistairPrestidge you know what, i think thats it! cheers

Comment: `from any instance with the appserver security group`.. How? there is no option to do that. You can only use the network from another sec group